# Combining numeric column values in large pandas DataFrame for duplicate rows without combining string

Tags: python, pandas

I have an extremely large pandas DataFrame with multiple rows for a single value `'Standard'` under column `'account_type'` but different numeric values for different rows in other column headers.

Is there a way to combine all numeric values for `'Standard'` without combining the string for every row? I have 180 columns that I need this done for.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
['Standard', 0.2],
['Standard', 0.3],
['Standard', 0.2],
['Standard', 0.4],
['Standard', 0.6],
['Standard', 0.3]], 
columns=['account_type',  'cost'])
```

Only want:

```
account_type   cost
'Standard'     2.0
```

Minimal coding experience so apologies if not clear.

Comment: `df.groupby('account_type', as_index=False).sum()`

Comment: Didn't mention but I have around 180 columns so don't want to type out each column name in the code. Just want to base everything around account_type and have all 180 columns combine.

Comment: Do you need to combine all rows for `Standard` preserving the number of columns (sum all rows in a given column)? Or do you also need to collapse all of the columns and rows into a single number for Standard?

Comment: Combine all rows for 'Standard' preserving number of columns and combining numeric values for all other columns @ALollz

Comment: @ALollz - Solution is not groupby, dupe is wrong.

Comment: @geds133 - added solution for sum of all numeric columns.

Comment: @jezrael. Sure then remove the dupe. The provided example just didn't match the actual problem.

Comment: @geds133 - So need filter only `Standard` rows and `sum` all numeric columns?

Comment: Sure. Many Thanks @jezrael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter only `Standard` rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and for new `DataFrame` use constructor:

```
a = df.loc[df['account_type'] == 'Standard', 'cost'].sum()
print (a)
2.0

df = pd.DataFrame([['Standard', a]], columns=['account_type',  'cost'])
print (df)
  account_type  cost
0     Standard   2.0
```

If all values are `Standard`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Standard', df['cost'].sum()]], columns=['account_type',  'cost'])
```

And if want all possible `acount_type` values is possible aggregate `sum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
['Standard1', 0.2],
['Standard1', 0.3],
['Standard1', 0.2],
['Standard2', 0.4],
['Standard2', 0.6],
['Standard', 0.3]], columns=['account_type',  'cost'])

print (df)
  account_type  cost
0    Standard1   0.2
1    Standard1   0.3
2    Standard1   0.2
3    Standard2   0.4
4    Standard2   0.6
5     Standard   0.3

df1 = df.groupby('account_type', as_index=False)['cost'].sum()
print (df1)
  account_type  cost
0     Standard   0.3
1    Standard1   0.7
2    Standard2   1.0
```

EDIT:

If need `sum` of all numeric columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'account_type':['Standard'] * 5 + ['another val'],
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

print (df)
  account_type  B  C  D  E  F
0     Standard  4  7  1  5  a
1     Standard  5  8  3  3  a
2     Standard  4  9  5  6  a
3     Standard  5  4  7  9  b
4     Standard  5  2  1  2  b
5  another val  4  3  0  4  b

cols = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
s = df.loc[df['account_type'] == 'Standard', cols].sum()
print (s)
B    23
C    30
D    17
E    25
dtype: int64

df1 = s.to_frame().T
df1.insert(0, 'account_type', 'Standard')
print (df1)
  account_type   B   C   D   E
0     Standard  23  30  17  25
```

Comment: Congratz for 300k!